# Base64ToImage in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: image, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, base64

In my Windows 8 app I get an image as base64 string. Now I am looking for a method that converts the string so that I can include it in my XAML image, something like this:

```
public static Image Base64ToImage(string s)
{
    // How To?
}
```

I have seen many solutions but all of them use classes/methods that are not available in Windows 8 store apps. Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method could look like this:

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> Base64ToImage(string base64)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(buffer.AsBuffer());
        stream.Seek(0);
        bitmap.SetSource(stream);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Excellent and short solution! I added a try/catch block in case the base64 string is not valid.